# Dual space isomorphism of vector space with finite support

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis

> Suppose that $k$ is a field. Consider the vector space $k^{\times \mathbb{N}}:= \{(x_0, x_1, x_2,...) ∣ x_i \in k\}$ and its subspace $k^{\oplus N}:= \{(x_0, x_1, x_2, . . .) \in k^\mathbb{N}∣ x_i ≠ 0$ for finitely many $i\}$. Prove that $(k^{\oplus \mathbb{N}})^*\simeq k^{\times \mathbb{N}}$. ($(k^{\oplus \mathbb{N}})^*$ is dual space of $k^{\oplus\mathbb{N}}$)

**Attempt:**

We can take bases of $k^{\oplus\mathbb{N}}$ as infinite dimensional vectors such that every basis has a coordinate $1$ on the place where $x_i\neq 0$ and all other coordinates are $0$. Since vectors in $k^{\oplus\mathbb{N}}$ have finitely many coordinates that are not equal to $0$, then the dual bases are $f_1=x_{i_1}, f_2=x_{i_2},..., f_n=x_{i_n}$, which is finite. My question is that why this finite dimensional vector space can be isomorphic to infinite dimensional vector space $k^{\times\mathbb{N}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong idea about dual bases. For any $i\in \mathbb{N}$, there is a linear form $f_i$ which takes $x=(x_0,x_1,\dots)$ to $x_i\in k$. So there are an infinite number of those $f_i$. You seem to be confused by the fact that for a given vector $x$, only a finite number of the $f_i(x)$ will be non-zero. This is true: if you fix $x$, only a finite number of $f_i$ matter; but for any $i$, $f_i$ is non-zero on some vector, so it is not a trivial linear form.

This being said, the subtlety of the exercise lies elsewhere: the $f_i$ are linearly independent, but they are not a basis of the dual (there is no such thing as a "dual basis" in infinite dimension, unless topology enters the mix). In infinite dimension, the dual is bigger than the original space.

To see this, take any linear form $f$. It is characterized by its values $f(e_i)$ where $e_i=(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots)$. And for *any* sequence $(a_i)$, you can define $f$ by the fact that $f(e_i)=a_i$. Even when an infinite number of $a_i$ are non-zero. This is why the dual is isomorphic to $k^{\times \mathbb{N}}$ and not $k^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$ (which would be the case if we only allowed the sequences $a_i$ with a finite number of non-zero terms).

The key point to understand is that even if all $a_i$ are non-zero, for a fixed $x$, we have a *finite* decomposition $x=\sum x_ie_i$, so $f(x)=\sum x_ia_i$ is a *finite* sum. So even though $f$ requires an infinite number of parameters, when applying $f$ to any vector, only a finite number of these parameters intervene.

Answer (score 1):

It isn’t finite dimensional. I don’t understand what you mean exactly by “$f_1 = x_{i_1}$, $f_2 = x_{i_2}$, …, $f_n = x_{i_n}$” being the “dual bases” when $x_{i_1}$, …, $x_{i_n}$ are supposed to be coordinates, so elements in $k$.

Do you mean “the dual base” perhaps? What is $f_i$ exactly, as a map $k^{\oplus ℕ} → k$?

You can get to the result more abstractly by observing that there’s in general an isomorphism

$$\hom (\bigoplus_{i ∈ I} V_i, W) \cong \prod_{i ∈ I} \hom (V_i, W).$$
The isomorphisms are given by splitting into components and addition respectively.

Setting then $I = ℕ$, $V_i = k$ and $W = k$ yields the specific result.